# Radio button in Gridcolumn won't trigger binding

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have two devexpress gridcolumns with one radio button in each.

In code behind when I am setting a value to the properties binding to the radio button, the binding takes. But when I am changing selected radio button in the view the selected won't trigger the property.

what am I missing?

```
<dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding IsOrder}"
                      Header="Order" 
                      Visible="{Binding IsVisible}"
                      Width="60">
  <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         GroupName="{Binding RowData.Row.Number}"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding 
                               Path=View.DataContext.StatusNotHandled}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
```

```
<dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding IsNotOrder}"
                      Header="Not order" 
                      Visible="{Binding IsVisible}"
                      Width="60">
  <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         GroupName="{Binding RowData.Row.Number}"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding 
                                Path=View.DataContext.StatusNotHandled}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is most likely the fact that you are trying to use a non-DX control as an edit of a GridColumn which is discouraged explicitly by DevExpress. Try replacing the RadioButton with a DX-CheckEdit for example.

Key-take-aways from my experience:

1. do NOT use non-DX controls as InplaceEdits of a GridControl.
2. for DX-edits to work correctly when assigned in a CellTemplate
   their name has to be set to 'PART_Editor'. Omitting that will lead to problems with navigation etc.
3. Use the the GridColumn.FieldName-property instead of binding. This should make the InplaceEdit inherit the binding from its Column automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Change your binding for `IsChecked` to `RowData.Row.IsOrder`, it will probably solve your selection problem. You can read a little bit more information on using `RowData.Row` over `Value` or `Data` [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T190244/binding-path-in-gridcontrol-editgridcelldata).

On another note, as @Sancho Panza said, you're always better to stick with BaseEdit descendant when dealing with CellTemplate.

This is one of the advantages of using a BaseEdit descendant in [CellTemplate](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.ColumnBase.CellTemplate) :

> For the DevExpress Data Editors (the BaseEdit class's descendants), you can set the editor's Name property to PART_Editor. In this case, the GridControl automatically adjusts its appearance and synchronizes the editor with the source field specified by the ColumnBase.FieldName or ColumnBase.Binding properties.
>   You can use any binding with an editor named PART_Editor. In this case, the GridControl's logic of getting/setting the editor's value is disabled.

The final decision of using a BaseEdit descendant or a WPF RadioButton is yours, but I also recommend sticking with BaseEdit.